# Weil group and conjugacy classes of cocharacters

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, group-schemes, reductive-groups

We have the following setup: $G$ a compact reductive group over $\mathbb{R}$, $T$ a maximal Torus, $U^1$ the real algebraic Torus and $W$ the Weil group of $T$

In [Variétiés de Shimura](https://publications.ias.edu/node/380) Lemma 1.2.4 p.258 Deligne concludes the following isomorphism:

$$ Hom(U^1,G)/G(\mathbb{R})\cong Hom(\mathbb{G}_m, G_\mathbb{C})/G_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C})$$ 
from these isomorphisms: 
$$ Hom(U^1,T)/W\cong Hom(U^1,G)/G(R)\\
Hom(\mathbb{G}_{m},T_\mathbb{C})/W\cong Hom(\mathbb{G}_m,G_\mathbb{C})/G_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C})$$

1. What is the "Weil group of T"? I am aware of the definition of a Weil group of a local field, maybe he just means the Weil group of the local field over which $T$ is defined?
2. I do not know how to conclude.

I know any two maximal tori are conjugate and that the image of a torus will be contained in a torus, which will give me e.g. a map $Hom(\mathbb{G}_{m},T_\mathbb{C})\to Hom(\mathbb{G}_m,G_\mathbb{C})/G_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C})$, which is surjective, but from there I am stuck. Is he maybe referring to the We**y**l group of $T$?

Given the two latter isomorphisms, how do I conclude the first one?
Is there an "obvious" isomorphism $Hom(U^1,T)/W\to Hom(\mathbb{G}_{m},T_\mathbb{C})/W$ given by complexification?

I would also welcome a reference which possibly elaborates on such isomorphisms between tori and reductive groups.

Comment: He is definitely referring to the Weyl group of $T$!

Comment: Yes, this seems very sensible. I am still missing out on the conclusion so far though